# How to chain Material 3 Design TextInputLayout with TextInputEditText using Android constraint layout?

Tags: android-studio, material-design, android-constraintlayout, android-textinputedittext

I created constraint layout large form with many text inputs. Sometimes with two or three text inputs in one horizontal line. Now is neccesary to add Material 3 Design and there is problem to chain text inputs between them.

Is there some other solution with use of constraint layout or I will have to go to older linear layout etc.?